# iOS not rotating

Tags: ios, rotation

I have a view controller with a navigation item. The view inside the navigation item rotates, but the navigation bar at top does not. I don't understand why only part of the application is rotating.

Comment: Do you mean that the navigation bar rotates but doesn't resize, or does it not rotate at all, nor resize at all?

Comment: Personally, I suspect you're missing a 

    (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}

somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's seems to be pretty much about this in google.

This one looks promising

[UINavigationBar autoresizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538111/uinavigationbar-autoresizing)