# How to resize UINavigationBar on rotation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

If I set a `UINavigationController` as my `self.window.rootViewController` in AppDelegate, when I rotate the device the `UINavigationBar` resizes to be slightly smaller.

How can I mimic this behaviour when using a tab controller as my root view? I've tried setting the `AutoresizingMask` properly on the tab bars child navigation controller views, but to no avail. The view rotates properly but the `UINavigationBar` stays the same 44pt height.

I've tried changing the frame during my `layoutSubviews` method as so: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height = 32.0` which kinda works but is buggy and doesn't feel correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I missed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538111/uinavigationbar-autoresizing/3600768#3600768) when researching earlier. Looks like it fixes the problem.